# D3.js zoomable map

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/nkhine/3150901) and would like to have it reviewed:

```
function thisClient() {
  "use strict"
  var self = this

  var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    centered, data

    this.init = function () {
      //now.receiveLocation = function(message) {
      //    console.log(message)
      //    // FIXME only push markers depending on the country/adm1 level
      //    self.drawMarker(message)
      //}
      self.drawMap()
    }

  this.fileExists = function (url) {
    "use strict"
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    http.open('HEAD', url, false)
    http.send()
    return http.status != 404
  }

  this.quantize = function (d) {
    "use strict"
    return "q" + Math.floor(getCountyNorm(d.id) * 10) + "-9";
  }

  // Map code
  this.drawMap = function () {
    "use strict"
    var map = d3.geo.equirectangular().scale(150)
    self.path = d3.geo.path().projection(map)

    self.svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "90%")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + "  " + height)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")

    // Add a transparent rect so that zoomMap works if user clicks on SVG
    self.svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "background")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("click", self.zoomMap)

    // Add g element to load country paths
    self.g = self.svg.append("g")
      .attr("id", "countries")
    // Load topojson data
    d3.json("./topo/world.json", function (topology) {
      self.g.selectAll("path")
      //.data(topology.features)
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries).geometries)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", self.path)
        .attr("id", function (d) {
        return d.properties.name
      })
      //.attr("class", data ? self.quantize : null)
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "orange")
          .append("svg:title")
          .text(d.properties.name)
        //self.activateTooltip(d.properties.name)
      })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .style("fill", "#aaa")
        //self.deactivateTooltip()
      })
        .on("click", self.zoomMap)
      // Remove Antarctica
      self.g.select("#Antarctica").remove()
    })
  } // end drawMap

  this.zoomMap = function (d) {
    "use strict"
    var x, y, k

    if (d && centered !== d) {
      var centroid = self.path.centroid(d)
      x = centroid[0]
      y = centroid[1]
      k = 2
      centered = d
      self.loadCountry(d, x, y, k)
    } else {
      // zoom out, this happens when user clicks on the same country
      x = width / 2
      y = height / 2
      k = 1
      self.centered = null
      // as we zoom out we want to remove the country layer
      self.svg.selectAll("#country").remove()
    }

    self.g.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function (d) {
      return d === centered
    })

    self.g.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .delay(100)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px")

  } // end zoom function

  this.loadCountry = function (d, x, y, k) {
    "use strict"
    // we remove the country
    self.svg.selectAll("#country").remove()
    // load country json file
    var adm1_key = d.id + "_adm1"
    var adm1_path = "./topo/" + d.id + "_adm1.json"

    // check to see if country file exists
    if (!self.fileExists(adm1_path)) {
      console.log("We couldn't find that country!")
    } else {
      console.log("Load country overlay")
      var country = self.svg.append("g").attr("id", "country")

      self.countryGroup = self.svg.select("#country")
      d3.json(adm1_path, function (error, topology) {
        var regions = topology.objects
        for (var adm1_key in regions) {
          var o = regions[adm1_key]
        }
        self.countryGroup.selectAll("path")
          .data(topojson.object(topology, o).geometries)
          .enter().append("path")
          .attr("d", self.path)
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
          .attr("id", function (d) {
          return d.properties.NAME_1
        })
          .classed("country", true)
          .attr("class", "country")
          .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px")
          .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .style("fill", "#6C0")
            .append("svg:title")
            .text(d.properties.NAME_1)
        })
          .on("mouseout", function (d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .style("fill", "#000000")
        })
          .on("click", function (d) {
          console.log('clicked on country')
          self.loadProjects()
        })
      })
    } // end else
  }

  this.loadProjects = function () {
    console.log('loadProjects')

  } // end loadProjects

  this.init()
} // end thisClient

jQuery(function () {
  thisClient = new thisClient()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- Because you have `use strict` on top in `function thisClient() {`, you do not need it within functions declared within `thisClient` like `this.fileExists`
- I am all for Spartan coding but variable like `d` and `k` have to go
- Using the http method `HEAD` is cool, I learned something
- Don't keep commented out code
- You do not use semicolons, please use semicolons; what will the neighbors say?
- The lack of semicolons also breaks JsHint
- Your aligning is a bit odd in this part:

  ```
  d3.json("./topo/world.json", function (topology) {
    self.g.selectAll("path")
    //.data(topology.features)
    .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries).geometries)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", self.path)
      .attr("id", function (d) {
      return d.properties.name
    })
    //.attr("class", data ? self.quantize : null)
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "orange")
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(d.properties.name)
      //self.activateTooltip(d.properties.name)
    })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "#aaa")
      //self.deactivateTooltip()
    })
      .on("click", self.zoomMap)
  ```

  I would put the `.on` next tothe `})`:

  ```
  d3.json("./topo/world.json", function (topology) {
    self.g.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries).geometries)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", self.path)
      .attr("id", function (d) {
      return d.properties.name
    }).on("mouseover", function (d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "orange")
        .append("svg:title")
        .text(d.properties.name)
      //self.activateTooltip(d.properties.name)
    }).on("mouseout", function (d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "#aaa")
      //self.deactivateTooltip()
    }).on("click", self.zoomMap)
  ```
- It is kind of evil to create a constructor and then replace it with an instance of it self, you cant possibly name that variable correctly ;)
- Please do not use `console.log` in production code
- You should assign color constants `.style("fill", "#6C0")` to properly named variables, somewhere on the top
- There must be better ways than this to get the last `adm1_key`:

  ```
  for (var adm1_key in regions) {
    var o = regions[adm1_key]
  }
  ```